# Error: \begin{table} ended by \end{document}

Tags: tables

This latex code works:

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\usepackage{rotating}


\lstnewenvironment{test}[1][]{%
    \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    autogobble=true,#1
    }%
}{}



\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
%
%% \usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%
%% this packaes are useful for nice algorithms
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}



\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
%\makesavenoteenv{table}


\begin{document}


%\chapter{Example Data from CSV Files produced by Parsing}
%\label{cha:appendixF}

Note: Entries in some of the columns are not mentioned in the main body of this bachelor thesis because they are irrelevant to the parsing and analysis but was collected during data parsing process from web API. Short description of these entries will be provided in this appendix. 

\newpage

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|} \hline
sendWallet                         & receWallet                         & tranHashString                                                   & time                & value\_bitcoin & value\_dollar         & type       & estChanAddr & outputIndex \\ \hline
1474...oPEx & 1Ent...g56p & f3ac...d62e & 2016-01-14T07:24:53 & 10724          & 0.04592553            & pubkeyhash & null        & 2513        \\ \hline
1474...oPEx & 1KvD...Zeqw & f3ac...d62e & 2016-01-14T07:24:53 & 29340          & 0.12564855   & pubkeyhash & null        & 2514 \footnote{abc} \\  \hline     
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example data in the csv files containing transaction information, the entries in the columns of ``sendWallet'' (corresponds to the value of ``primWallAdd'' of the wallet which spends the bitcoin in the transaction), ``receWallet'' (corresponds to the value of ``primWallAdd'' of the wallet which receives the bitcoin in the transaction) and tranHashString (the hash of the transaction) are shortened so that the table can be fit to the page. The column ``outputIndex'' indicate the index of the output in the output list of the transaction.}
\label{tab:tranCSV}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

However, after I uncommenting the line `%\makesavenoteenv{table}`,
it throws the error in the title. 
(I need this line for footnotes in tables.)

What is the reason?

Comment: It work on here https://latexbase.com/.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand it. Do you want a copy of it?

Comment: Which main errors? I have changed the `{l}`  to the correct `{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}`. However, it still does not work after I added the package and the other two lines.

Comment: updated question.

Comment: There is no error in the log you show (you do not get the error message for H as you have an old Latex so it silently ignores )

Answer (score 1):

The posted code (even after the edit) produces

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `H'.
```

so removing `[H]`

it runs without error but warns

```
Overfull \hbox (348.23416pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 14--19
```

so the table is *far* too wide.

However if I add the specified footnote package lines no error is produced.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\title{Getting started}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
%\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|} \hline
sendWallet                         & receWallet                         & tranHashString                                                   & time                & value\_bitcoin & value\_dollar         & type       & estChanAddr & outputIndex \\ \hline
1474...oPEx & 1Ent...g56p & f3ac...d62e & 2016-01-14T07:24:53 & 10724          & 0.04592553            & pubkeyhash & null        & 2513        \\ \hline
1474...oPEx & 1KvD...Zeqw & f3ac...d62e & 2016-01-14T07:24:53 & 29340          & 0.12564855   & pubkeyhash & null        & 2514  \\  \hline     
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example data in the csv files containing transaction information, the entries in the columns of ``sendWallet'' (corresponds to the value of ``primWallAdd'' of the wallet which spends the bitcoin in the transaction), ``receWallet'' (corresponds to the value of ``primWallAdd'' of the wallet which receives the bitcoin in the transaction) and tranHashString (the hash of the transaction) are shortened so that the table can be fit to the page. The column ``outputIndex'' indicate the index of the output in the output list of the transaction.}
\label{tab:tranCSV}
\end{table}
%\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: When I copy the code in your answer to this site: https://latexbase.com/, it says `Oops... there's a compiler error! Switch to the log view by clicking above to learn more.` Why is it so?

Comment: I just updated the code. It does not work after uncommenting the corresponding line in Texmaker.

Comment: @Aqqqq `\makesavenoteenv{table}` appears to be incompatible with the version of `table` defined by the `float` package which is used by `algorithm`  if you comment out `algorithm` and remove `[H]` (also defined by `float package` then it works  I do not think it can really work to use makesavenoteenv with a floating environment like table, latex does not support footnotes on floats